# How to wait for COM port receive event before sending more data in a loop

Tags: delphi, loops, event-handling, serial-port

I'm working on a small component for writing and reading AT Commands using an old Sony Ericsson phone.
Sending and writing to/from the phone is no problem at all, however I would like to be able to pause my SendATCmd function and wait for the COM Port component to notify me with a Notification Event, and then resume the SendATCmd function again.

Scenario: I want to get the count of SMS messages in the phone.
Normally I'd just tell the phone: Hey, how many SMS messages do you have?
and the phone would reply in the notification event.
Thats all good.

But what I really want to do is something like

```
if SendATCmd('CountSMS')>0 then
  for 0 to SMSCount do
    AddSMSToList;
```

The code for SendATCmd looks like this:

```
function TSE_Z1010.SendATCmd(Cmd: string): TATResult;
begin
  fCOMPort.PutString(Cmd); //Sending AT command

  //Here is where I would like to pause this function
  //wait for the fCOMPort to notify me when data is available
  //and then resume this function again.

  result:=fTMPATResult;

end;
```

I've tried using a while-loop, pause, etc etc, but nothing's worked except for one thing, and that's when I put a ShowMessage where the pause should be.
I don't know how ShowMessage works internally but it seems that it doesn't halt the program like while-loop and pause do.

====================

Fixed it.

All I had to do was to add Forms in the uses clause, and then I added while fTMPATResult.Full=false do Application.ProcessMessages; in the part where I wanted to pause the procedure.

"fTMPATResult" is the variable where the incoming COM Port data is stored, globally within the component.

Comment: if you have an answer, please add it as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Comment: it said i dont have enough points to add an answer to my own question.

Comment: What is the Serial communication Component you use (fCOMPort)?

Comment: It's the one from Asynch Pro. Its available on sourceforge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While AsyncPro does have some solutions for this (ontriggerdata), they are event based and make code difficult to read/understand.

here is SendAndWaitForResponse with AsyncPro (like Remy suggested):

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
 ...
private
    IOEvent           : THandle; // used for IO events
    IORx              : string;
    Comport           : TapdComport;
...


procedure TForm1.ComportTriggerAvail(CP: TObject; Count: Word);

var i       : integer;

begin
 for i:=1 to Count do
  IORx:=IORx+Comport.GetChar;
 SetEvent(IOEvent);
end;

function TForm1.SerialSAWR(tx : string; TimeOut : integer) : boolean;
begin
 Result := False;
 try
  IORx := ''; // your global var
  ResetEvent(IOEvent);
  Comport.PutString(tx);
  Result := WaitForSingleObject(IOEvent, TimeOut) = WAIT_OBJECT_0;
 except
  on E : Exception do
   // dosomething with exception
 end;
end;

// constructor part
IOEvent := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, nil);
// destructor part
 if IOEvent <> 0 then
  CloseHandle(IOEvent);
```

Best solution is to create a thread with the comport so your GUI won't be blocked.
I have several applications in production with Asyncpro this way and it works like a charm...

Comment: I don't understand where to put the constructor part and destructor :(

Comment: @ElCouz: that depends. If you are using a form , then the OnCreate event and OnDestroy event are good candidates.

Comment: Thanks! :) Another thing... i don't see anywhere in this code where is the RX part?I was looking for a command like send and get string (waiting for answer) I see that you send and wait for an answer but it doesnt capture the answer :(

Comment: @ElCouz: you can check the received data in the IoRx variable (after the WaitForSingleObject call)

Comment: if serialsawr('@',5000) then
  showmessage(IOrx); .This send the @ caracter but i cannot catch any reply!

Comment: @ElCouz, ask a new question with your problem and then we can take a look at it :)

Comment: Allright i will open a new question later tonight ... i hope you can answer to it. You seem to have alot of experience handling serial communication! Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Any time you need to call `Application.ProcessMessages()` manually, you need to rethink your code design. Doubly so when calling it in a loop.

I do not know how Asynch Pro works, but the Win32 API has a `WaitCommEvent()` function that does what you are asking for. You call that function to ask the serial port for notification of the desired event(s) and then you can use either `WaitForOverlappedResult()` or `WaitForSingleObject()` to wait for those events to actually occur, depending on whether the serial port is operating in overlapped mode or not. No message processing is needed. I would be surprised if Asynch Pro does not somehow expose that functionality.