# How to send a string (serial port) , wait (timeout) and catch the reply string?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, function, serial-port, communication

After reading this very interesting topic on stackoverflow --> [How to wait for COM port receive event before sending more data in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050045/how-to-wait-for-com-port-receive-event-before-sending-more-data-in-a-loop)

I've ran into many problems and i've tried many solutions ... nothing work well unfortunately !

Many serial port libraries are event-driven and i'm having a hard time understanding them.

I've tried with Asyncpro, Synaser and TComport.

Is it possible to have a function like this:

SerialSendandReply(tx string here,timeout) return rx string and if timeout send a error string

Response from the device are withing milliseconds a blocking way to do it would be better?

Like this:

```
Dosomething here
showmessage(SerialSendandReply('test',100 )); //100 ms timeout
dosomething else
```

With this code

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
 ...
private
    IOEvent           : THandle; // used for IO events
    IORx              : string;
    Comport           : TapdComport;
...


procedure TForm1.ComportTriggerAvail(CP: TObject; Count: Word);

var i       : integer;

begin
 for i:=1 to Count do
  IORx:=IORx+Comport.GetChar;
 SetEvent(IOEvent);
end;

function TForm1.SerialSAWR(tx : string; TimeOut : integer) : boolean;
begin
 Result := False;
 try
  IORx := ''; // your global var
  ResetEvent(IOEvent);
  Comport.PutString(tx);
  Result := WaitForSingleObject(IOEvent, TimeOut) = WAIT_OBJECT_0;
 except
  on E : Exception do
   // dosomething with exception
 end;
end;

// constructor part
IOEvent := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, nil);
// destructor part
 if IOEvent <> 0 then
  CloseHandle(IOEvent);
```

Then i've tried to call this function :

```
if SerialSAWR('test'; 5000) then showmessage(IORx);
```

**Sending is working great but doesn't return anything in the string.**

Any advices?

Thank you very much!

Regards,
Laurent

Comment: You should be receiving after the 'wait' timeouts - even if the 'Result' is false, no? The wait is blocking the main thread, you have to receive and set the event in another thread.

Comment: I'm not very experienced with threads. Is it possible to not use them? Latency between query (send string) and answer from the device is less than 100 ms (worst case scenario). Queries and answers sent are less than 4 bytes long and called once or twice per hour. Do you think i can manage that in the main thread ?

Comment: What I can think of is to set a global boolean flag at receive time (ComportTriggerAvail), while the sending code (SerialSAWR) processes messages (Application.ProcessMessages) in a loop at most ~100ms while waiting for the flag to be set. Not elegant...

Comment: I understand your point ... I wanted a simple function which could check if the device is alive without going deep into threading. I'm still learning Delphi as long as you can cite a good reference which can help me build a working serial thread which synchronize perfectly with the main thread... i'm open minded :)

Comment: I read the question you linked. I don't understand how but according to that page this code works, it's the accepted answer. Obviously I miss something...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: In fact, the code from my answer came from a threaded application.

Comment: @ElCouz: you need to move your serial code in a thread, then my answer will work

Comment: @ELCouz: I am busy right now and I will respond with a solution later this day...

Comment: @whos - Ok, thanks, it figures. But currently that answer is misleading, as we have seen here..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz yeah I know, I will fix that later :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched for nrComm Lib (v9.31)... very simple of use and well supported.

The only drawback is that isn't free and open source ... but it's worth it !

It's also thread-safe which is good too :).

Thank you very much everyone for the replies!

Answer (score 1):

I use TComPort and have created the following routine to do what you ask. TComPort monitors received characters in its monitoring thread and my routine waits for characters without calling Application.ProcessMessages. It may not be the most elegant code but it works fine.

```
function TArtTComPort.SerialPort_AwaitChars(AMinLength: integer;
      ATerminator: char; AQtyAfterTerm: integer; ARaise: boolean): string;
    var
      fDueBy : TDateTime;

      function IsEndOfReplyOrTimeout( var AStr : string ) : boolean;
      var
       I : integer;
      begin
        Result := False;
        If ATerminator <> #0 then
          begin
          I := Length( AStr ) - AQtyAfterTerm;
          If I > 0 then
            Result := AStr[I] = ATerminator;
          end;
        If not Result then
          Result := Length(AStr) >= AMinLength;


        // Un-comment this next line to disable the timeout.
        //Exit;

        If not Result then
          begin
          Result := Now > fDueBy;
          If Result then
            If ARaise then
              raise EArtTComPort.Create( 'Serial port reply timeout' )
            else
              AStr := '';
          end;
      end;

    var
      Events : TComEvents;
      iCount : integer;
      S : string;
    begin
      Assert( AMinLength > 0, 'Invalid minimum length' );

      If not FComPort.Connected then
        begin
        Result := '';
        Exit;
        end;

      fDueBy := Now + (FTimeoutMS * TDMSec );

      Result := '';


      Repeat

          // Setup events to wait for:
          Events := [evRxChar, evTxEmpty, evRxFlag, evRing, evBreak,
                   evCTS, evDSR, evError, evRLSD, evRx80Full];

          // Wait until at least one event happens.
          FComPort.WaitForEvent(
            Events,
            FStopEvent.Handle,
            FTimeOutMS);

          If Events = [] then // timeout
            begin
            If ARaise then
              raise EArtTComPort.Create( 'Serial port reply timeout' )
            end
           else
            begin
            If evRxChar in Events then
              begin
              iCount := FComport.InputCount;
              FComPort.ReadStr( S, iCount );
              Result := Result + S;
              end;
            end;

      until IsEndOfReplyOrTimeout( Result );


    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do async I/O from the main thread. This will never play well with the GUI.

Doing complex async I/O is better suited in a separate thread. I have a blocking serial communication package (I think Synaser also has a blocking mode) and a function like this:

```
function TransmitReceive(const msg: AnsiString; var reply: AnsiString; 
  timeOut: Integer): Boolean;
```

Put the complex code logic inside a `thread.execute` and trig the start of the logic with an event signal.

Communicate results etc to the main thread through `PostMessage` calls for example.

Comment: I've searched through synaser.pas... I cannot find anything related to `TransmitReceive` function. Do you have a little code snippet to inspire me?

Comment: In SynaSer you can call `function TBlockSerial.RecvBufferStr(Length: Integer; Timeout: Integer): AnsiString;` to get the answer with a timeout. My `TransmitReceive()` function is just a combination of send and receive. There are overloaded function calls which can break out early if an end character is defined for example. Remember to do all this in a thread.