# Delphi Com Port Application

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tcomport

I have a Barcode Scanner device and I am trying to write an application using Delphi 7.
I used Dejan's ComPort component and I can connect the device succesfully. I also can read the string from the device and able to send messages between STX/ETX.
But I have a problem. I use Comport's RxChar event to read the string from the device and able to send commands with the buttons I created.

The problem is; how to understand if data recieved from barcode scanner? I can not handle it. Could you please help me? I have checked some examples over google some says use Async method but I dont know how to do it.

Comment: Please share what you've got so far.

Comment: The scanner is hardwired into the port, so any data received on the port has to be from the scanner and nothing else. You know how to detect data on the port. You know how to read data from the port. So what is the actual problem?

Comment: Its simple, I want to understand if I recieved the data correctly? Because after scanning any 2Dbarcode the scanner fires a string ... The first string is the content of my 2D barcode but then it fires another weird string like (HDCPROK) etc.. so my program confueses on what this string is... I tried counting the string and then making it work but its not a good idea.. Please check this topic. its almost same but i didnt understand the solution in there...   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050045/how-to-wait-for-com-port-receive-event-before-sending-more-data-in-a-loop

Comment: Could this weird string be a part of scanner protocol?

Comment: What do the programming docs for the device say?